# Skype prevents computer from shutdown

Tags: windows, windows-10, shutdown, skype

Skype is preventing the computer from shutting down. This error dialog appears on the shutdown screen *(the one where you can only take pictures of the screen)* and without user interaction, leads back to the desktop showing this:

> **Skype.exe - Application Error**
>   The instruction at 0x0000000062B1E31B referenced memory at 0x00000000058C07F8. The memory could not be read.

I am using **Windows 10 x64 Pro** and of course the **latest** version of Skype. Skype is running for the entire time the computer is turned on.

This error is persistent with every reinstallation of Windows. As of yet, I have no clue where this comes from and therefore I don't know which information to provide except the obvious (OS version, Skype version). **The workaround** is to exit Skype, wait a few seconds and then trigger shutdown. **But is there an actual solution to this issue?**

[image: error message]

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.
The simplest solution (updating driver doesn't work) is...
adding `taskkill` command to logoff and shut down scripts.

Prepare file `kill_skype.bat`: 
put `taskkill` command inside

```
taskkill /IM skype.exe /F
```

Go to Local Group Policy Editor: 
Computer configuration -> Windows settings -> Scripts -> Shutdown -> Properties -> Add -> find kill_skype.bat file.

User configuration  -> Windows settings -> Scripts -> Logoff -> Properties -> Add -> find kill_skype.bat file.

Now your computer will logoff and shutdown without error.

Comment: That's a very clever idea ;) I cannot test it, since I have another computer by now and here, the issue is not present. But this seems very plausible, so +1 :)

Comment: I ended up doing the same, sorry for not sharing it with you.

Answer (score 1):

This issue might be linked to your ASUS Xonar DG Audio Device if you have it. Try updating those drivers and see if that helps. Another solution that sometimes help is to disable "I sing out" sound in Skype options->Sounds.

Comment: I am using UniXonar drivers (version 1822 1.75a r2). This is because the original drivers don't work and the current UniXonar version also doesn't work. Removing the sign-out sound didn't help.

Comment: I'd like to now confirm, that the Asus Uni Xonar drivers **were** the issue. I installed them, because the original drivers were not working back then. The current version of the original Asus Xonar drivers for my audio card are working and I don't have issues with Skype anymore. Thanks! :)

Comment: I'm sorry @krizajb, but I have to revert my previous statement. With original & latest version Xonar drivers, the issue is still reproducible (shutdown with Skype running). I will unaccept the answer keeping issue solving in foreground, sorry for this. Hopefully this issue then gets more attention until it is resolved, especially since I saw multiple reports of it.